# Do I have 32 bit, 64-bit Java or both?

Tags: java

I see this in the Java Control Panel

```
Platform: 1.8
Product: 1.80_131
Location: http://java.sun.com/product/autodl/j2se
path: c:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_131\javaw.exe
architecture: x86_64
```

The Architecture value, x86_64, suggest both 64 and 32 bit but the Java web app that I am trying to access, Oracle Discoverer, part of the Enterprise Business Suite, only works with the 64 bit Internet Explorer, suggesting to me that 32 bit Java is not installed. Is it? Or is there a problem with it?

Comment: x86_64 means it is 64 bit, otherwise it would have just been x86.

Comment: Makes sense. Go for an official answer and get a few points. thank you

Comment: Is there any problem with installing the 32 Java 8 side-by-side on the same machine?

Comment: *only works with the 64 bit Internet Explorer, suggesting to me that 32 bit Java is not installed* this makes little sense, what is the actual error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x86_64` means it is a 64 bit architecture (see also [x86-64 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)), if it had been 32 bit, it would just have been `x86` (see [x86 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)).

In any case, it is perfectly fine to install a 32 bit Java next to a 64 bit Java.

Answer (score 2):

[x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) and [x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) are both *architectures*; the first one is `32` bits and the second one is `64` bits. You can install as many java versions as you want side-by-side, you would just point to the one you want your application to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. x86_64 means 64 bit java.And the path "c:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_131\javaw.exe" also proves that you installed 64 bit java, otherwise, the path should start with "C:\Program Files (x86)".
2. 64 bit Internet Explorer can access both 32 bit and 64 bit java web servers.
3. Internet Explorer does not need to run on java environment(unless you are developing a Applet application.) which means you can run Internet Explorer without java.

Conclusion:
Your environment has installed 64 bit java, and there is no problem to you!